# Sometimes syncing gets stuck with dd

Tags: dd, io, synchronization

Sometimes when I use `dd` then `sync` or use `dd` with `conv=fsync`, the syncing process gets stuck, but sometimes not, with exactly the same input and output targets and configuration.

```
dd if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie-lite.img of=/dev/sdg conv=fsyn
sync # freeze here
```

or

```
dd if=2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie-lite.img of=/dev/sdg conv=fsync
```

I experienced this inconsistent behavior on different distros like Ubuntu, Linux Mint (long time ago) and now on Gentoo and 4 different different machines.

Comment: Does `iostat` shows any I/O activity on /dev/sdg while `sync` is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find myself quite often in a situation when `pv image_file | dd of=/dev/slow_usb_stick` shows that first few hundred megabytes just fly (to the buffer), then the transfer slows down badly. When `dd` exits there is entire buffer to flush. I then `sync` in order to remove the stick and I have to wait few more minutes because the buffer is large and the device is slow.

So maybe it is about patience. I suppose the buffer size depends on available memory. Sometimes the buffer can be very large and `sync` "gets stuck", sometimes not. That's a guess.

---

Another phenomenon I observed: the `sync` flushes all buffers (i.e. to all devices). Few times I wanted to remove USB stick (after `dd` to it), invoked `sync` to do so, but at the same time my HDD was busy with massive write operations. Data for HDD kept coming too fast for the buffer to get empty. Frozen `sync` had nothing to do with `dd` then. For that reason I wish `sync` could target specific device and exit regardless of all the other devices.

**Edit:**

My wish has come true. In Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS I have `sync (GNU coreutils) 8.25` which *can* target specific filesystems. Hooray!

Comment: You must be right I found about Page Cache and it is really use the free memory to cache data for i/o operations. Iguess using conv=fsync for dd instead of sync after dd is the solution about what you wrote in the second part of your answear. Tahnks